# C program loop to go back and forward to control led lights

Tags: c, loops

I am helping my daughter with a programming issue and I need some help with the following loop. The idea is to illuminate 8 led's in sequence from right to left and back again. The loop runs once but then it stops. For some reason, the environment she uses doesn't allow her to step into the debugger. I am a C# guy so a bit clueless on C. Can anyone help?

```
while (1) {
        //poll timer events and react if any occur
        static char pattern = 0b00000001;   //uint8_t instead of char?
        if (timer.event == TRUE) {
            //timer.event = FALSE;
            char Current = LEDS_GET();
            //char leftTest = LEDS_GET();
            
            if (dir == RIGHT && Current == 0b00000001) {
                dir = LEFT;
            }
            if (dir == LEFT && Current == 0b10000000) {
                dir = RIGHT;
            }
            if (dir == RIGHT) {
                //uint8_t pattern = LEDS_GET();
                pattern >>= 1;
                LEDS_SET(pattern);
            }
            if (dir == LEFT) {
                //uint8_t pattern = LEDS_GET();
                pattern <<= 1;
                LEDS_SET(pattern);
            }
            timer.event = FALSE;
        }

    }
    //LEDS_GET() gets the current LED state and returns a char
    //LEDS_SET() sets a new pattern onto the LEDs
    //LEFT = 0
    //RIGHT = 1
    //int dir = LEFT //this is set before while loop
    //LEDS_SET(0b00000001) //beginning sequence for LEDs
```

Comment: This may be an issue due to the optimization. How is `timer` defined?

Comment: replace `char` with `unsigned char`

Comment: Also you don't need `Current`, your `pattern` is already tracking the state.

Comment: Checking both - direction and the current pattern is superfluous, checking pattern alone is enough to switch the direction.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as expected:

```
unsigned char Pattern = 1;
int Dir = 1;
while (1) {
    LEDS_SET(Pattern);
    if (Dir == 1) {
        if (Pattern == 0x80) {
            Pattern >>= 1;
            Dir = 0;
        }
        else
            Pattern <<= 1;
    }
    else {
        if (Pattern == 1) {
            Pattern <<= 1;
            Dir = 0;
        }
        else
            Pattern >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will pass this on to her.